# Jquery datepicker year range not working properly

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker.I have given date range from 1964 to 1990 . But without selecting year it takes current year such as 2013.What is the problem in jquery datepicker.I have enclosed coding here.

```
  jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('.driver_dob').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange:  '1964:1991'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add [defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate), like

```
jQuery('.driver_dob').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange:  '1964:1991',
      defaultDate: '01-01-1964'
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3qwd/)

Comment: Just a note to anyone who might make the same mistake: call the `datepicker()` function only once, because calling it twice -- first without paramaters, then with parameters, as I was doing, accidentally -- causes the parameters to be ignored.